# How to connect to a Postgres Docker container running by docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I have a C# project that uses a Postgres database.
When I use a Docker container the C# code can connect to it and it works.
I can also connect with DBeaver for creating and populate the tables for the first time.

Here is the Docker command to start the container:
(multiline for readability)

```
docker run --name alpha-postgres -p 5040:5432
    -e POSTGRES_DB=alpha
    -e POSTGRES_USER=alpha
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alpha
    -d postgres
```

and here is the connection string use:

```
Host=localhost; Port=5040; Database=alpha; Username=alpha; Password=alpha
```

Now the problem.
When I use docker-compose for both the services (dotnet C# and Postgres) I can see the "same" container in Docker Desktop and the C# app can use it, but I cannot connect to it using DBeaver (Connection time out).
Here the relevant part of the docker-compose (the Postgres service):

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
  alpha-network:
    name: alpha-network

services:
  alpha.pgsql:
    container_name: alpha-pgsql
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: unless-stopped    
    ports:
      - "5040:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
      POSTGRES_DB: "alpha"
      POSTGRES_USER: "alpha"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "alpha"
    networks:
      - alpha-network
```

The connection works well from another service (the dotnet C# application) inside the docker-compose, on the same network.
Why when the container is started from the docker-compose it is not reachable from localhost ? ... and how can I do it?

### [EDIT]

Added the definition of the network in the docker-compose.

### [SOLVED]

Turned out the issue was the just port number.
Switching it from 5040 to 5041 or 5060 it works as expected.

5040 is also used in another similar project but it is not started since the machine was restarted. The other docker compose was always down and there isn't any container running on Docker.
I cannot see the reason why it should not work using the same port of other projects (if you used them alternatively).
I think that is what sometime happens in Windows; it just block some port that you used before (also wuith Node.js project I have this behaviour sometime).
No issue or other "synmptoms" that can you make thing of this problem.

Comment: How have you defined the `alpha-network`? It needs to use  a bridge driver if you want the container reachable from the host.

Comment: It set it with defaults, so "bridge" driver. I edited the post adding that info.